# Plus operation on large numbers

Tags: c++, c

There are two n-bit numbers which are store in two byte array (little-endian).

for example : 40-bit number can be represented by: `char c[5] = {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x01} ;`, it is `0xffffffff01`.

My question is ***How to implement the plus operation on two n-bit number efficiently in C or C++*** ?

In fact I want to implement the basic operation on large number which is represented by byte array. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Repetition of addition with carry from the lower digit.

Comment: If that is your required format, then you'll have to implement it manually. But that fits inside a 64-bit `uint64_t`, so you could pack it inside one. If you might need more than 64 bits, then why re-invent the wheel when there are plenty of arbitrary-precision libraries around?

Comment: @Adam So we can learn things.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I know but it seem hard to do bit operation.

Comment: May be take a look at [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)?

Comment: @Adam I'm curious how to implement it.

Comment: @gongzhitaao It is a huge project...

Comment: @KudoCC I'm aware of that :P

Comment: @gongzhitaao It's hard to analyze in a short time I think. If you have used it, can you show me the basic idea of that?

Comment: copy that 40-bit array into the low 40 bits of uint64_t

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc The number would can be more than 48 bit length, the 40-bit array is an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic approach is the same as the one you learned in grade school. Starting at the least significant bytes, add the two bytes along with the incoming carry. If there is an out carry, carry it to the next set.

Of course today's processors are either 32 or 64 bit, so it makes more sense to use `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` as the base type instead of `char`. Note you likely want *unsinged*, not signed.

You can always look at code from libraries written for this purpose. GMP has a "mini-gmp" pair of .h/.c files that implements the most basic ops. You can browse them online here: [mini-gmp.h](https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp-5.1/file/c5010c039373/mini-gmp/mini-gmp.h), [mini-gmp.c](https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp-5.1/file/c5010c039373/mini-gmp/mini-gmp.c). In particular, the function you're interested in is `mpz_add`. Google finds [example usage](https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-discuss/2008-March/003085.html). `mpz_add` delegates to other functions, but the meat appears to be this function on line 393:

```
mp_limb_t
mpn_add_n (mp_ptr rp, mp_srcptr ap, mp_srcptr bp, mp_size_t n)
{
  mp_size_t i;
  mp_limb_t cy;

  for (i = 0, cy = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      mp_limb_t a, b, r;
      a = ap[i]; b = bp[i];
      r = a + cy;
      cy = (r < cy);
      r += b;
      cy += (r < b);
      rp[i] = r;
    }
  return cy;
}
```

I'll leave it up to you to figure out what the types mean, how memory allocation works, etc., but think of an `mp_limb_t` as your `char`.

Comment: It's very kind of you, it really help me. But it seems that if `mp_limb_t` is an signed type, we will get the wrong answer. For example (let's say `mp_limb_t` is `char`): cy(which is the carry ) is 0 and a is 0x7f, b is 0x01, after `r=a+cy; cy = (r < cy);`, r is 0x7f, cy is still 0. Then `r += b;`, r is 0x8f now which is -1, so r<b is true, after `cy += (r<b);`, cy is 1 and r is 0x8f. So mp_lib_t should be unsigned type, I'm not sure if a unsigned char 0xff plus unsigned char 0x01 will result 0x00 which the algorithm depends on.

Comment: 0x7f + 0x01 == 0x80, not 0x8f. Signed 0x80 is -128. -1 is 0xff. Look up "Two's complement" if that does not make sense. You've just discovered that it makes no sense to use signed "limbs", to follow GMP's nomenclature. `typedef unsigned long mp_limb_t;`. *unsigned*. You want to have a single sign bit somewhere, not one for every byte. See line 56 of the .h file for GMP's. Also follow the delegations from `mpz_add`. You'll notice that because they don't use 2's complement they have to use their `sub` operation to handle adding a negative number.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you modify your answer to make it accurate, as you know `mp_limb_t` should not be signed.